# Asp.net control Id is not matching in the javascript recently

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, web

A asp.net project was working fine since 2-3 years but now it started giving some control ID not avalilabe errors in the javascript. The controls ID were hardcoded in javascript like "ct100_mainControl_txtName" but now when I check the HTML source file the Control ID is "mainControl_txtName". I made the ID changes in the javascript it is working fine now. But how did this error appear now. What could have changed. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You've updated the website from 2.0 or 3.5 to .Net 4.0 or more. See the linked question for more details.

Comment: How can I convert my project Target framework from 2.0 to 4.0 without using visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

When I am working with asp.net webforms I prefer to use class names for my jquery selectors. The reason for the change of id could be that you moved the control around to another container or something.

eg.

```
<input type="text" class="someclass" />
```

Then use

```
$('input.someclass')....
```

This way you are sure that when the id changes your javascript will still work.

Comment: Yes this will work but I want to know how did that error occurred now.